# carrying product_id value to an extra added page through url

Tags: php, opencart

I am using OpenCart. I want to give a link from `product_form.tpl` to another page. I mean I have added a tab called 'Allocation' in which I have given a button 'Add Allocation' which should redirect an external page. I'd like also to provide the `product_id` within this link but it's not working properly...

Here is my code (`product_form.tpl`)

```
<div id="tab-allocate">
        <table class="list"><tr><td align="center"><a href="allocation.php?product_id=&product_id" target="_blank" class="copybutton" style="width:120px;">ADD ALLOCATION</a></td></tr></table>
        </div>
```

But `allocation.php?product_id=&product_id` is not working, it goes to `allocate.php` page 
but doesn't carry the product_id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A couple of problems with this. The & seperates name=value pairs, if you are trying to assign anything to product_id the & will kill your assignment. where is the actual product_id you are trying to copy? is it in javascript? is it a hidden form value? is it a php variable?

Comment: Oh, actually if i click on edit, it takes the product_id in url like this `<a href="<?php echo $action['href']; ?>"><?php echo $action['text']; ?></a>`, in controller its like this `foreach ($results as $result) {
   $action = array();
   
   $action[] = array(
    'text' => $this->language->get('text_edit'),
    'href' => $this->url->link('catalog/product/update', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
   );` , but am not getting how to do like this for my variable

Comment: in product_form.tpl, where is product_id declared?

Comment: @Seth Cohen:  I got it resolved. Thank you very much for your precious time

Comment: ah, so it was a php variable. i thought that might have been the case. glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's something wrong in your passing parameter, please try like that

`<a href="allocation.php?product_id=product_id" target="_blank" class="copybutton" style="width:120px;">`

Your previous style work to pass two parameter. eg 
`<a href="allocation.php?product_id=product_id&second_id=Second_id" target="_blank" class="copybutton" style="width:120px;">`

Hope this help

Ps. You can also use like that
 `$this->request->post['product_id']` **OR** `$this->request->get['product_id']`

Comment: It doesn't work :(. Before passing it, i need to get the product_id, i need to declare it somewhere in the controller->product.php, am not getting where and how

Comment: So, where your product id come from? from cart?

Comment: i got it resolved... I capruted product_id on that page by Get method then i used like this `<a href="allocation.php?product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>"`
thanks for the quick response .. thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

What a messy HTML...

Change that link to this one:

```html
<a href="allocation.php?product_id=<?php echo $result['product_id']; ?>" target="_blank" class="copybutton" style="width:120px;">ADD ALLOCATION</a>
```

This should work. And put the CSS styles into the CSS files (`catalog/view/themes/<YOUR_THEME>/css/stylesheet.css`).